# Extract each column as image from scanned pdf

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, document-layout-analysis

I need to crop each column from scanned pdf. I tried lots of solution from here but none of them worked.

For example I have below image.

[image: original_img]

I am using below script to remove horizontal and vertical lines because with those getting each column is not easy for me.

```
import cv2

SCALE = 4
def show_scaled(name, img):
    try:
        h, w = img.shape
    except ValueError:
        h, w, _ = img.shape
    cv2.imshow(name, cv2.resize(img, (w // SCALE, h // SCALE)))


image = cv2.imread('3-1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
show_scaled("horizontal detected lines", detected_lines)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

# Remove vertical
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 15))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
show_scaled("vertical detected lines", detected_lines)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

# show_scaled('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite("contours.png", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Result is: [image]

After removing borders I use below script to get each column.

```
import cv2

SCALE = 4
AREA_THRESHOLD = 427505.0 / 2


def show_scaled(name, img):
    try:
        h, w = img.shape
    except ValueError:
        h, w, _ = img.shape
    cv2.imshow(name, cv2.resize(img, (w // SCALE, h // SCALE)))


def main():
    base_img = cv2.imread("contours.png")
    img = base_img.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    show_scaled("original", gray)

    # black and white, and inverted, because
    # white pixels are treated as objects in
    # contour detection
    thresholded = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        gray, 255,
        cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
        25,
        15
    )
    show_scaled('thresholded', thresholded)
    # I use a kernel that is wide enough to connect characters
    # but not text blocks, and tall enough to connect lines.
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 110))
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    show_scaled("closing", closing)

    for i in range(len(contours)):
        contour = contours[i]
        convex_contour = cv2.convexHull(contour)
        area = cv2.contourArea(convex_contour)
        if area > AREA_THRESHOLD:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [convex_contour], -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
            [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            cropped_image = base_img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            res = cv2.imwrite("/cropped-images/column" + str(i) + ".png", cropped_image)
            print(res)

    show_scaled("contours", img)
    cv2.imwrite("/tmp/contours.png", img)
    cv2.waitKey()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result is:

[image]

Now there are two problem about what I did. First one is "KULLANMA" text at right upper corner should also removed. I cant basically crop image because it can be smaller or bigger so pixel values between that text and below text can be changed.

[image]

Second in second script, opencv also draw contour for header section like in image below.

[image]

How can I get only columns images and remove right upper text from image?

Edit:

Script also should support 3,4,6,8 columns pdfs. I tested with 3 column and result is not I expected. I need more generalised solution. Can anyone help me please?

I expect to have these three column has separate contour but result is like below.

[image]

Comment: Actually the job is comparison with the file you mentioned. I am gonna read the docx file you mention and scanned and formatted pdf file I added on thread. Then I should do ocr on that pdf then compare text if they are equal.

Comment: Actually I don't expect %100 reliability from OCR. If I feed left column or right column to the Tesseract, results are enough okay for the task. Thats why I want to extract each column separately.

Comment: Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KJ The question is how I can extract columns as image separately. If I can get column images I can feed them to tesseract. Probably I should use OpenCV to make image preprocessing but dont know how.